# How to debug a program wrapped in a libtool script?

Tags: debugging, gdb, libtool

I have a project involving

- shared libraries ie: `mylib.so`
- (test) program using these shared libraries ie: `test_mylib`

When I try to run `gdb` on `test_mylib`, it prints:

```
"test_mylib": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

When I use the real program (`.libs/test_mylib`) directly instead, it still complains:

```
.libs/test_mylib: can't load library 'libhello.so.0'
```

How Can I run gdb to debug my program ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is problem I ran into a couples of days ago and there is no generic answer on SO yet. Only special cases. Here is the answer I found on this page: http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Debugging-executables.html

Until the program is installed, the system does not know where to look for the shared objects. They usually lies in `.libs` sub-directory of their source folder.

Libtool generates a convenience script to allow debugging before the actual installation is done (who wants to install buggy software *before*, debug it *after*?)

Fortunately, the generated script provides a helper for this:

```
libtool --mode=execute gdb test_mylib
```

Comment: On an OS X machine, I get `error: libtool: unknown option character \`-' in: --mode=execute` (my workaround was to install to a prefix, but perhaps --disable-shared as mentioned below is simpler in the long run)

Answer (score 8):

The solution recommended by the libtool docs is to use *static linking* during development, as I decribed at: [Build libtool application with static linking to local components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37191903/86967)

To do this, use the [`--disable-shared`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Static_002donly-libraries.html) option to the `./configure` script.

For example:

```
./configure --enable-debug --disable-shared
```

Now the generated executable is a directly executable binary rather than a libtool script.

This has the added benefit of roughly halving the build time.

Comment: Other background info without the `--disabled-shared` solution: https://autotools.io/libtool/wrappers.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Debugging-executables.html