# using libtool e gdb

Tags: gdb, autotools, libtool

I'm working on a project that uses GNU autotools, so in order to debug the code using gdb, I'm running gdb from within libtool:

```
libtool --mode=execute gdbtui foobar
```

Is it possible to reload a modified version of the project without the annoyance of having to quit gdb/libtool and restart?

Comment: For background, when a program is built using autotools, one can't debug it directly using gdb. See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148668/how-to-debug-a-program-wrapped-in-a-libtool-script

Answer (score 2):

`libtool --mode=execute` creates a temporary executable which is passed to gdb. This executable is removed upon rebuild. The trick is to recreate it with something like

```
libtool --mode=execute echo ./hello
```

(Libtool will recreate the temporary executable and pass its name to `echo` command. You can use any other command instead of `echo`, e.g. `true` to suppress output, or even non-existing one.)

To reload the executable use gdb [`file`*`filename`*](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#index-file) command  file. Executable real name is displayed by gdb upon start:

```
$ libtool --mode=execute gdb --args ./hello
...
Reading symbols from /path/to/.libs/lt-hello...done.
(gdb)
```

It is also displayed by gdb [`info inferiors`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html#index-info-inferiors) command:

```
(gdb) info inferiors 
  Num  Description       Executable        
* 1    <null>            /path/to/.libs/lt-hello
```

and, of course, by the above `echo` command.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to discern what exactly you are asking, but I hope I understood you correctly.

Yes, you can normally run the debugged command again from within `gdb` as long as it was started with `gdb` in the first place. In fact this is the common workflow for `gdb`. Use it in one window/tab/pane to debug your stuff and fix the code in another, rebuild in a third etc.

One way `gdb` gets started is this one:

```
# gdb --args command arg1 arg2 ...
```

another is:

```
# gdb command
```

in the latter case you would anyway only start the program from the gdb prompt like this.

```
(gdb) run arg1 arg2 ...
```

in the former the arguments are *implied* (and remembered by `gdb`). In either case you can retrieve the arguments after the fact using:

```
(gdb) show args
```

It is common to rebuild the program once you hit, analyzed and fixed a bug re-run it using only `run` (which reuses the previous arguments) and verify the fix or continue debugging another problem.

Comment: But when a program is built using GNU autotools, one can't invoke gdb directly from the command line as you suggest. Rather, it's necessary to invoke gdb indirectly via 'libtool', as in the one-liner I put in my question. It's in that scenario my question stands. For background, refer to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148668/how-to-debug-a-program-wrapped-in-a-libtool-script

Comment: @user1404316: and you tried running `show args` from within `gdb`? And yes, it *is* possible to run the ready program manually with `gdb` afterward. Not sure what you want, however, is at all possible. You should add those clarifications to your question, though. On the other hand why shouldn't you be able to separate the build and debug/execute stage *with* `libtool` and use the above method as I described it? Most times during debugging the library dependencies won't change, so you should still be fine with re-`run`ning the process.

Comment: `libtool` by default only creates a shell script (that is named just like the binary) and the binary itself is put into the .libs/ subdirectory. The real binary will only appear after `make install` or when using `libtool --mode=execute`. See the answer from @Illia K.

Comment: This is all answered in the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148668/how-to-debug-a-program-wrapped-in-a-libtool-script?noredirect=1&lq=1 This question is kind of a follow up question, asking for the ability to reload the executable from within a gdb session.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Ilia's answer (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105922/gdb-set-variable-using-pipe-and-awk) answer on how to parse the executable name to a gdb variable) a solution is to define the following `custom make` command in `~/.gdbinit`:

```
define lmake
  python gdb.execute('set $f = "' + str(gdb.selected_inferior().progspace.filename) + '"')
  make
  eval "file %s", $f
end
```