# Print `file` path in GDB in a parsable way

Tags: gdb

I'm looking for a way to print out the name of the loaded `file` in GDB.

The previous version of this question was oriented about symbols, but in fact I need to know what was provided to the `file` command, or what was provided as a GDB startup argument.

I can have it printed in several different ways, but they are not ideal.

One approach is to enter the `file` command without an argument:

```
(gdb) file
No executable file now.
Discard symbol table from `/path/to.elf'? (y or n)
```

Another is to use `maint info symtabs`, as it starts with:

```
{ objfile /path/to.elf ((struct objfile *) 0xADDRESS)
```

As suggested by @employed-russian, I can use `info file` to get some output, but it's also not easy to parse inside GDB.

```
(gdb) info file
Symbols from "/path/to.elf".
```

I'm looking for something more straightforward, that I wouldn't have to parse - or at least a reasonable way to parse it and store in a GDB variable.

Python API is also an option, but I'd rather have a solution that works in a pythonless GDB as well.

Update: thanks to the suggestion of @mark-plotnick I was able to find another question that solved my very problem, in a different way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62118493/882200

The exact answer to my issue is:

```
(gdb) python gdb.execute('set $f = "' + str(gdb.selected_inferior().progspace.filename) + '"')
(gdb) p $f
$2 = "/tmp/a.out"
```

Comment: What exactly do you need, the executable or the symbols path? Because they are not always the same.

Comment: @ssbssa updated the question to be more clear - I mean "what was provided to the `file` command"

Comment: Without python, I'm pretty sure `info file` provides the easiest to parse output.

Comment: Does `pipe maint info symtabs | awk '$1 == "{" && $2 == "objfile" { print $3 }'` do what you want?

Comment: Thank you for this, it was a great pointer! I couldn't pass that easily to a variable, but also found a question that addressed my very question, but in a different way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105922/how-to-set-variable-using-pipe-and-awk-in-gdb

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a way to print out the name of the loaded symbols file

Tthere is not necessarily "*the* loaded symbols file" -- there could be many (one or two for the main binary, and another one or two for each loaded shared library).

`info file` and `info shared` provide some of the info.

Comment: Fair enough. Rephrased the question to indicate that I'm interested in "what was provided to the `file` command"