# Build libtool application with static linking to local components

Tags: libtool

I am working with an open-source application that uses `libtool` in its build process.  I would like to *statically link* the local components of the application with the following intended benefits:

- doesn't require libtool wrapper to launch
- function calls aren't indirected by dynamic linking during debugging
- avoid unintended dynamic linking to existing system-installed library

Is there a standard option to the build process that does this?

Due to dependencies on non-static system libraries I can't just use:

```
./configure LDFLAGS='-static'
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done!  Use the [`--disable-shared`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Static_002donly-libraries.html) option.

For example:

```
./configure --enable-debug --disable-shared
```

Now the generated executable is a directly executable binary rather than a libtool script.

This has the added benefit of roughly halving the build time.